# Virtual host error: client denied by server configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, kohana

I try to setup kohana 3 project as virtual host.

Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "D:/Devel/matysart/matysart_dev1"
  ServerName matysart-one.local
  ServerAlias www.matysart-one.local
  DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Error (403):

> [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration:
>   D:/Devel/matysart/matysart_dev1/

.htaccess

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Could somebody help?

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess in that location?
Does the .htaccess (if present) or your Apache configuration conatain something like `Order deny,allow
 Deny from all` or `Deny from 127.0.0.1`?

Comment: yes it has, it standard kohana htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting up a `Directory` container like this within your VirtualHost brackets

```
<Directory "D:/Devel/matysart/matysart_dev1">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews 
   AllowOverride None
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```